# Groovy script in JMETER

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

I was trying to add groovy (Groovy 2.4.3) to the JMeter 2.13.

I am placing all the %groovy_home%/lib/*.jars in %java_home%/lib/ext/groovy-lib/*.jar

I added the classpath in jmeter.property file (search_paths=/lib/ext/groovy-lib)

The problem is after starting JMeter, I am able to use Groovy in BSF elements (assertions, Samplers etc) but the JSR223 elements (assertions, samplers etc) are not showing the Groovy script language option.

[image: BSF Showing Groovy]

[image: JSR223 Missing Groovy]

Any help would be valuable
Thanks

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If response was helpful you should upvote and accept

Answer (score 6):

The simplest and easiest way to get groovy engine up and running is:

1. Download the [latest version of groovy-all.jar from Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all)
2. Drop it to the /lib folder of your JMeter installation. /lib/ext folder is actually for JMeter core and extensions)
3. Restart JMeter if it's running (jar pickup process is not dynamic, it is also applicable to any other libraries like [Jmeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/), [JUnit tests](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter), user.properties file change, etc.)
4. After restart you should see groovy along with the .jar version in parentheses

Answer (score 4):

You must use user.classpath and groovy-all-xxx.jar

> List of paths that JMeter will search for utility and plugin dependency classes.
>    Use your platform path separator (as per System Property "**path.separator**") to separate multiple paths.
>    A path item can either be a jar file or a directory.
>    Any jar file in such a directory will be automatically included,
>    jar files in sub directories are ignored.
>    The given value is in addition to any jars found in the lib directory.
>    All entries will be added to the class path of the system class loader
>    and also to the path of the JMeter internal loader.
>    Paths with spaces may cause problems for the JVM

So it should be:

> user.classpath=/lib/ext/groovy-lib/groovy-all-xxx.jar

Answer (score 0):

> You can also install utility Jar files in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext, or you can set the property user.classpath in jmeter.properties
>
> Note that setting the CLASSPATH environment variable will have no effect. This is because JMeter is started with "java -jar", and the java command silently ignores the CLASSPATH variable, and the -classpath/-cp options when -jar is used. [This occurs with all Java programs, not just JMeter.]

According to [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), but for me this made the magic :
Just edit user.classpath property in jmeter.properties.

> user.classpath="YOUR-GROOVY-HOME-DIR"/lib

Surprisingly using $GROOVY_HOME did not work and I had to mention the groovy home path instead of referring to system environment variable, and as [@ubik-load-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460802/ubik-load-pack) mentioned if you need more items to be added to this property, use your operating system classpath separator character( Linux=":", Windows=";" )